# Where can I find accepted values for crypto.generateKeyPairSync()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to generate a key pair for the `secp256r1` elliptic curve.

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';
const key = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'secp256r1'
});
console.log(key);
```

When executing this code I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Invalid EC curve name
```

I understand that this curve, or the name I'm using, isn't supported by Node.js (my version is `v15.12.0`)? Where can I find a list of all valid curve names that are accepted for use with `generateKeyPairSync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the OpenSSL source that's bundled with your Node version: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v15.12.0/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/ec_curve.c#L3163

Comment: As per that source code, to use "secp256r1", one should use the curve name  "prime256v1" as they both refer to same curve.